# Ember how to update isAuthenticated after logging in

Tags: ember.js, devise, ember-simple-auth

I have an app setup using ember-cli 0.1.1 and I'm using ember-simple-auth (along with devise cli plugin) for login. In my application template, I have a menu with a conditional wrapped around it:

```
{{#if session.isAuthenticated }}
  <div class="nav_user">
    <p>{{session.user_name}}</p>
    <p class="user_account">{{#link-to 'account-settings'}}<img src="assets/images/gear.png" />{{/link-to}}</p>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>{{#link-to 'horses'}}My Horses{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li>{{#link-to 'veterinarians'}}Veterinarians{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li>{{#link-to 'documents'}}Documents{{/link-to}}</li>
    <li>{{#link-to 'notes'}}Notes{{/link-to}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li><a {{action 'invalidateSession'}}>Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
{{/if}}
```

The problem is that after a successful login, I transition to another route and if I immediately open the menu, the non-authenticated menu is what appears.  If I refresh, then I get the correct menu contents.  I'm looking for a way to updat session.isAuthenticated after a successful login, prior to transitioning to the new route.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the session.isAuthenticated is already set to true prior to the transition.

Comment: Showing only this template is not enough. Please also show application route, application and login controllers.